# Set VALUE and LABEL to an ITEM JComboBox in Java

Tags: java, label, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox where the items are the results of a query. The combo shows all the categories names taken from a query, right? Ok, it works. Now I need to give each item a value, which would be the ID of the product.

This is what I've got so far:

```
    final JComboBox proveedorCombo = new JComboBox();

    contentPanel.add(proveedorCombo);

    ProveedorDAO dao = new ProveedorDAO();

    List<Proveedor> proveedor = dao.getAll();

    Object[][] elementos = new Object[proveedor.size()][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < proveedor.size(); i++) {
        Proveedor p = proveedor.get(i);
        elementos[i][0] = p.getId();
        elementos[i][1] = p.getNombre();
        proveedorCombo.addItem(elementos[i][1]);
    }
```

As you can see in the code, the "label" of each item is the name of it. Now, how can I set each item its ID so I can manipulate after?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the IDs of the values as the values in your JComboBox, and use a custom ListCellRenderer to look up the name for an ID value.

You can do this by building a Map of names by their ID, and having your renderer return names for values.